# HoughLinesP with IplImage

Tags: opencv, hough-transform, iplimage

I'm trying to apply the probabilistic Hough transformation on an image, but I get this compiler error:

> invalid initialization of reference of type ‘cv::InputArray {aka const cv::_InputArray&}’ from expression of type ‘IplImage* {aka _IplImage*}’
>
> /opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp:482:19: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void cv::HoughLinesP(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, double, double, int, double, double)’

```
    IplImage *imageD, *src; //src -is read from a *.png and preprocessed  
    ...
    imgageO=imageD = cvCreateImage( cvSize(src->width,src->height), 8, 1 );
    cvCopy(src, imageO);
    ...
    HoughLinesP(imageD, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, PHTdThresh, PHTdmin, PHTdmax );
```

The first parameter of HLP() is InputArray image: – 8-bit, single-channel binary source image. The image may be modified by the function.

I think, I'm confused with the pointer handling here.
Moreover if i change the first parameter:
`HoughLinesP(*imageD, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, PHTdThresh, PHTdmin, PHTdmax );`

Than it compiles but in runtime i get core duped fort the line above:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file
> /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1308/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp,
> line 697 terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'cv::Exception'   what():
> /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1308/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:697: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray) says

> . You can assume that instead of InputArray/OutputArray you can always use Mat, std::vector<>, Matx<>, Vec<> or Scalar

You cannot pass an IplImage as an InputArray. You can work around the problem using the `Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false);` constructor. Your call to `HoughLinesP()` should be:

```
    HoughLinesP(Mat(imageD), lines, 1, CV_PI/180, PHTdThresh, PHTdmin, PHTdmax );
```